# Scala bazel Worker process did not return a WorkResponse:

Tags: scala, bazel

in BAZEL `WORKSPACE` file Ive added:

```
maven_jar(name = "com_chuusai_shapeless", artifact = "com.chuusai:shapeless_2.12:2.3.3")
```

in `BUILD` file also added this dependency:

```
deps = [
        "@com_chuusai_shapeless//jar"
    ],
```

In my code I have:

```
import shapeless._

object ShapelessPG {

  def run() = {
    val emp = Employee("Maciej", 1, true)
    val iceCream = IceCream("Vanillia", 5, false)

    println(s"emp: $emp iceCream: $iceCream")

    val genEmp = Generic[Employee]
    val genIce = Generic[IceCream]
```

when using `build` command but I have an error while running it:

```
bazel build :App
DEBUG: /private/var/tmp/_bazel_userXYZ/daf16773bdceeb074610f489c565e309/external/io_bazel_rules_scala/scala/scala_maven_import_external.bzl:59:9: 'jar_sha256' is deprecated. Please use 'artifact_sha256'
INFO: Analyzed target //:App (0 packages loaded, 0 targets configured).
INFO: Found 1 target...
ERROR: /Users/userXYZ/workspace/shapeless-bazel-zio-cats-playground/BUILD:3:1: scala //:App failed: Worker process did not return a WorkResponse:

---8<---8<--- Start of log snippet, file at /private/var/tmp/_bazel_userXYZ/daf16773bdceeb074610f489c565e309/bazel-workers/worker-3-Scalac.log ---8<---8<---
```

log file shows me:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file shapeless/ReprTypes
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
```

because of code:

```
val genEmp = Generic[Employee]
```

which works fine in sbt..

I have no idea how to fix it..
can someone help me ?

thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`maven_jar` does not pull in `shapeless`'s transitive dependencies, like `macro-compat` and `scala-library`. Use [`rules_jvm_external`](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_jvm_external) instead:

```py
load("@rules_jvm_external//:defs.bzl", "maven_install")

maven_install(
    artifacts = [
        "com.chuusai:shapeless_2.12:2.3.3",
    ],
    repositories = [
        "https://jcenter.bintray.com",
    ],
)
```

This will automatically resolve and fetch the `macro_compat` and other compile dependencies of `shapeless`. Then in the BUILD file, you can depend on `shapeless` like this:

```py
scala_library(
    name = "my_jar",
    srcs = # ...
    deps = [
        "@maven//:com_chuusai_shapeless_2_12",
    ],
)
```